# slim framework 3, fail to render html page

Tags: twig, slim, slim-3

Am using twig-view to render the html, currently am unable to change the Content type returned to the browser, i can see that content type returned by slim as json instead of html content hence all codes are displayed in browser

```
 $app->get('/',function(Request $req,Response $res,array $args) use ($app){
        $container = $app->getContainer();
        $container->view->render($res, 'test.html',[]);
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzB8l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition to **Zamrony P. Juhara** 
i have found that middleware i put was editing response to be returned as json content
***->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")***

```
/*
CORS
*/
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            //->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            //->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:2222/')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
});
```

so the browser was only getting json content response hence it was dumping all codes as json content instead of Content-Type: "text/html",
and that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to return the response like this:

```
return $container->view->render($res, 'test.html', []);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, that was another issue after wasting so much time have realize that i kept middleware which was blocking it

Comment: $app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
      //->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            //->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:2222/')
      ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
});